# LargeImageDownSizing Apple sample code - Restrict zoom level

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using `Apple` sample code `LargeImageDownSizing` to view my Large images. This code allows to zoom in to infinite level and zoom out at some level.

But some how i am unable to restrict the zoom in and zoom out, it has a scrollview which is having properties like :

```
self.maximumZoomScale = 5.00;
self.minimumZoomScale = .25f;
```

When i try to change the above values it just doesn't do anything, i am still able to zoom it infinite. Can any one help me on this, i need to restrict the zoom in and zoom out level.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just verified the above code. It seems to be working at my end. Are you only playing with these values or something else ?

Comment: are you able to restrict zoom both in and out? i am not doing anything else here.

Comment: Yes! Steps I have followed are, Downloaded the sample -> Changed these values "self.maximumZoomScale = 2.00f; self.minimumZoomScale = 1.00f; "
in ImageScrollView.m Class. It worked as expected.

Comment: i did try that as well, but if you do pinch it again and again it will zoom in. it just that the scale of pinching is restricted. :(

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The reason behind it is, it will keep the last scale value of the image as current value thats why the zoom is infinite.

if you are looking for something like, You have an image and user should be able to pinch in and pinch out? If yes, you can achieve this with the normal scrollview as well ?

Let me know if you are looking for something else or need more info for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for a guess as I did it in my code too and it worked, I would like to suggest -

The UIScrollView class can have a delegate that must adopt the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` in addition, the `maximum (maximumZoomScale)` and `minimum ( minimumZoomScale)` zoom scale must be different.

Or

under iOS 5.1 SDK (and some prior), it was possible to add a gesture recognizer to UIScrollView and be able to have it work in conjunction with panGestureRecognizer and pinchGestureRecognizer that are built into the UIScrollView.

under iOS 6.0 SDK, this behavior is apparently no longer really supported. the relevant documentation(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) does not so much explicitly forbid the behavior as it does define what the UIScrollView will do for touches that may or may not be related to pan and pinch.

Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the content. To make this determination, it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the scrolling itself. Subclasses can override the touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:, pagingEnabled, and touchesShouldCancelInContentView: methods (which are called by the scroll view) to affect how the scroll view handles scrolling gestures.